# Atributo 'required' do HTML pelo Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, atributos

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para que, quando o `activeBtn` estivesse checado, o `ordenadorBanners` ganhasse o atributo `required`, eu tentei o modelo abaixo mas não funcionou, gostaria de saber como fazer isso, e o "por que" de ter que fazer de tal jeito.

```
var $activeBtn = document.getElementById('btn-ativa');
var $ordenadorBanners = document.getElementById('ordem-banner');

if ($activeBtn.checked) {
   $ordenadorBanners.required = true;
}

<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="number" name="" min="1" max="10" id="ordem-banner" pattern="">
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="btn-ativa">
            <div class="slider round"></div>
            </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Cadastrar">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Coloca seu código html também.

Comment: Use o `prop`, da seguinte forma: `$ordenadorBanners.prop('required', true);` e após adicionar o `required` e o usuário tirar o `check` do `$activeBtn` use o `.removeAttr('required')`;

Comment: não funcionou :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tens de adicionar um auscultador de eventos para saberes quando é clicado ou não.

E depois podes usar a propriedade `.required` do elemento ou setar diretamente no HTML com `setAttribute`.

Exemplo:

```
var activeBtn = document.getElementById('btn-ativa');
var ordenadorBanners = document.getElementById('ordem-banner');
activeBtn.addEventListener('change', function() {
    ordenadorBanners.required = this.checked;
});
```

Ou então assim:

```
if (this.checked) ordenadorBanners.setAttribute('required', 'required');
else ordenadorBanners.removeAttribute('required', 'required');
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9y7282dg/

---

#### Notas:

- não usei o `$` no nome das variáveis pois em JavaScript isso não é habitual. Só para dar nomes a variáveis que são objetos jQuery ou de outras bibliotecas
- coloca esta código no final do `<body>` ou dentro de uma função que seja chamada quando o DOM estiver carregado e o HTML lido.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode resolver seu problema assim:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="number" name="" min="1" max="10" id="ordem-banner" pattern="">
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="btn-ativa" onclick="checkedBtnAtiva()">
            <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Cadastrar">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    checkedBtnAtiva();
    function checkedBtnAtiva(){
        var $activeBtn = document.getElementById('btn-ativa');
        var $ordenadorBanners = document.getElementById('ordem-banner');
        if ($activeBtn.checked) {
            $ordenadorBanners.required = true;
        }else{
            $ordenadorBanners.required = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Fazendo dessa forma você vai ter a verificação se esta *checado* ou não mesmo depois de carregado o *html*.
Lembre-se que você deve colocar o `script` depois do `html` em que ele vai trabalhar. De preferência no `footer`.
Espero ter ajudado.